# Param to array_map() not a string, PHPCS did not find it

Tags: php, compatibility

I did use something like

```
$foo = array_map(preg_quote, $some_list);
```

in my code. This worked fine with PHP 7.4, but did break with PHP 8.1.

The problem: I had to put preg_quote in quotes ;-), so

```
$foo = array_map('preg_quote', $some_list);
```

fixes my problem.

But: I did use phpcs with

```
--standard=PHPCompatibility --runtime-set testVersion 8.1
```

for all of my files, but I did not get any warning.

I am a bit nervous since I believed to find all incompabibility stuff with phpcs (or at least most).

Does anyone have an idea how to better find such incompatibilities with some "automatic" scan?

Comment: https://eusonlito.github.io/php-changes-cheatsheet/deprecated.html

Comment: I know the list, but how to find them "automatically". I cannot seek 100k code lines by hand!